# Gerador alfanumérico em formulário

Tags: php

Desenvolvi uma rotina de gerador alfanumérico, para ser colocado em um campo de um formulário. Porém, ele não gera a numeração. Alguém pode ajudar?

Esse campo abaixo:

```
<div class="guiaprest">
            <label name="tPrest"> 2- Nº Guia no Prestador</label>
        </div>
```

Aí fiz algumas pesquisas na internet, e achei um modelo e fiz assim:

```
<?php
function rand_sem_num_repetido($qtd_numeros,$limite_min,$limite_max){
    for($i=0;$i<=$qtd_numeros;$i++){
        $aux=rand($limite_min,$limite_max);

        if($i>=1){
            while(in_array($aux,$index)){
                $aux=rand($limite_min,$limite_max);
            }
        }

        $index[$i]=$aux;
    }

    return $index;
}
?>
```

Comment: Alfa numerico é letras+nums certo? Aí estás a só a gerar numeros

Comment: Sim. Verdade. Não havia reparado nisso. Mas mesmo sendo só números no código acima, ele não gera nada.

Comment: Tens de chamar a função. A mim correu bem o código que puseste, talvez só falte o `implode()`, vou responder em baixo

Comment: Ok Miguel, fico no aguardo.

Comment: Uma pergunta: `rand_sem_num_repetido` isto é porque é suposto não haver o mesmo numero repetido?

Comment: Sim. Ao gerar uma nova sequência, a mesma não poderá ser igual a anterior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function rand_sem_num_repetido($qtd_numeros,$limite_min,$limite_max){
    $index = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$qtd_numeros;$i++){
       $aux=rand($limite_min,$limite_max);

       if($i>=1){
           while(in_array($aux,$index)){
               $aux=rand($limite_min,$limite_max);
           }
       }

       $index[$i]=$aux;
    }
    return implode($index);
}
```

Tenta assim.
Mas essa função não gera um alfanumérico, e esse parâmetro de `$qtd_numeros` não vai limitar o número de caracteres pode vir 2 caracteres mas 1 número. (Ex.: 10 (Dez)). 
Para limitar o número de caracteres você pode alterar o retorno para `return substr(implode($index), 0, $qtd_numeros);` ou passar `$limite_min = 0` e `$limite_max = 9`.

Comment: Uma dúvida, eu deveria criar um arquivo com esse código e fazer a chamada no html  ou incluir direto no html?

Comment: Pode criar um arquivo, 'functions.php' para ficar mais organizado. Mas se preferir pode colocar no arquivo .php direto. Funciona das duas formas. Mas em um arquivo .html não funciona.

Comment: Pois bem,. Fiz a chamada dele dentro do meu arquivo e ainda sim não funcionou.